# convert django fileobject.chunks() into image

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am trying to create a progress bar for my file upload, so I need a way of know the state of the file been uploaded at any point in time.

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image']:
        file = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            image = ImageFile(io.BytesIO(chunk), name=file.name)
        filename = fs.save(file.name, content=image)
```

I am looking for a way of saving the chunk and later converting them into an image to be saved, I don't want to use the python read and right interface because i will be uploading the file to aws. can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: if you want to convert them later then keep `chunks` on list - don't create `ImageFile` for every chunk. You have to use only one `ImagFile` and only one `BytesIO`. And you should `write` chunks to this `BytesIO`. And after last chunk you have to move to its beginning - `seek(0)` to use it in `ImageFile`. You current code creates `image` only using last `chunk`

Comment: progressbar will need `JavaScript` and `AJAX` to ask server how many chunks it already get.

Comment: @furas thanks for your help, if I understand what you mean, you mean I should only use the last chunk from the generator chunks to create the image right?   you can give me an example if you dont mind. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it so it may not resolve all problems but you should create only one `BytesIO` before `for`-loop and use `write(chunk)` inside loop.

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image']:
        file = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        # only one `BytesIO`            
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        
        # append chunks 
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            buffer.write(chunk)
            
        # move to the beginning of buffer 
        # to use buffer with functions which will read from buffer
        buffer.seek(0) 
        
        # only one `ImageFile`
        image = ImageFile(buffer, name=file.name)

        filename = fs.save(file.name, content=image)
```

But it has other problem. Server will run it until it gets all chunks and page will have to wait for response from server. But at the same time page should run `JavaScript` with `AJAX` to send periodically request to other url to get information how many chunks was aready added to `BytesIO`.

But it makes other problem - `simple_upload` would have to keep this information (how many chunks it already get) in database or some file with information which user upload it - so later AJAX will get correct value when different users send files at the same time.

So it may have many problems to resolve.